# Hiding elements according to ID

Tags: react-native

I want to click on button an item and it will be hidden. I tried this  code but all the elements are hidden in the array. So how can I hide according to `item.post_id`?

```js
this.state = {
  hide::true
};

hide = () => {
  this.setState({
    hide:false
  })
}

render() {
  return (
    <View>
      {this.state.post.results.map((item, key) => {
        <View>
          {this.state.hide && (
            <>
              <View
                key={key}
              > 
                <Text>{item.title}</Text>
                <Text style={{ marginVertical: 10 }}>{item.text}</Text>
                <Button title="Hide" hide={this.hide} />
              </View>
            </>
          )}
        </View>
       )
     })}
    </View>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're mapping over the post.results then you should hide a button based on an id instead of a boolean. Otherwise you're going to hide all the buttons.

I think this is what you're trying to accomplish:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export default class UntitledComponent extends Component {
  state = {
    hiddenObject: null
  };

  hideButton = (key) => {
    this.setState({
      hiddenObject: key
    })
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        {this.state.post.results.map((item, key) => {
          // Only show when this key is not hidden
          this.state.hiddenObject !== key && (
            <View key={key}>
              <Text>{item.title}</Text>
              <Text style={{ marginVertical: 10 }}>{item.text}</Text>

              {/* NOTE: always bind to events:  () => this.hideButton(key) */}

              <Button onClick={() => this.hideButton(key)}>Hide</Button>
            </View>
          )
        })}
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```